# 2D and 3D ploting of w realated coefficients

Tags: matlab

Here of three coefficients with relation to w.

```
A = (38.6068*ω^2-0.37)/(0.1288*ω^2+0.1396)
B = ((18.58-0.3589*A)*ω^2)/(0.37)
C = ((30.45*A*B*ω^2 ))/(0.5*(0.1288*A*ω^2+0.1396*B))
```

I want to plot A and B in 2D and A,B and C in 3D in matlab for interval 
 `w = (0,0.48321)`.

Note : A,B,C have relation to each other in formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the code you've posted by using the following notation in the operations:

`./`, `.*`, `.^`

this allows to perform those operations on arrays "elemt-wise".

To plot `A` and `B` on a 2D chart you can use the `plot` built in function.

To plot `A`, `B` and `B` on a wD chart you can use the `plot3` built in function.

The 3D plot can only be a `line` and not a surface since being `C` a (1 x N) array (with `N=length(C)`).

The updated version of you code:

```
omega=0:.01:0.48321;
A = (38.6068*omega.^2-0.37)./(0.1288*omega.^2+0.1396);
B = ((18.58-0.3589*A).*omega.^2)/(0.37);
C = ((30.45*A.*B.*omega.^2 ))./(0.5*(0.1288*A.*omega.^2+0.1396.*B));
```

The 2D plot of `A`, `B`, `C`

```
figure
plot(omega,A,'r','linewidth',2)
hold on
plot(omega,B,'b','linewidth',2)
plot(omega,C,'k','linewidth',2)
grid on
legend('A','B','C','location','best')
```

[image]

The 3D plot

```
figure
plot3(A,B,C,'r','linewidth',2)
grid on
xlabel('Parm. A','fontweight','bold')
ylabel('Param. B','fontweight','bold')
zlabel('Param. C','fontweight','bold')
```

[image]